# ASP MVC child action renders form post to whatever URL the user is on

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a child action on a controller I want to render on the main layout of my web app. The partial rendered for the child action includes a form and I want the POST action to be whatever URL the user is on. Think webforms usercontrol and posting back to the same page!

This feels like it breaks the MVC model as you could be on a page that has a genuine postable action on the controller, with both the child action partial and main controller action pointing to. So where would the request be processed?

I could change the approach and post to a definitive action on a controller and then redirect back to the page the user was on, or handle the follow on state on a different view entirely.

Or I could keep the interaction on the same URL and use JavaScript for everything.

There are a few options so this question is more of a recommended approach:

I'm on MVC 4 currently.

Comment: Not like webforms at all, though the url does not change, you should handle it in different Actions. Check out the `Post-Redirect` pattern.

Comment: Can you not POST via AJAX to defined controller/action? Problem with re-direction back to the original page will go away automatically.

Comment: @mxmissile cheers, interesting pattern

Comment: @trailmax cheers, yeah a few options, I was curious hence the question. The specific feature has been simplified now :)